# Extracting numbers from NSStrings

Tags: ios, xcode

I have many NSString which look like this:

```
@"this is the content. The content of this string may vary, as well as the length, and my include any characters, with numbers Y = 295.000000 X = 207.500000"
```

The part Y = 295.000000 X = 207.500000 remains always the same, apart from the X and Y numbers which may change.

I need in some way to get those numbers and do something like this:

```
coordsFinal.x = 295.000000;
coordsFinal.y = 207.500000;
```

which would have the format of:

```
coordsFinal.x = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", trimmed string];
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to extract the numbers:

```
NSString *string = ...; // Your string
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"Y = (\\d+.\\d+) X = (\\d+.\\d+)" options:0 error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
if (match) {
    NSRange yRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *yString = [string substringWithRange:yRange];
    NSRange xRange = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
    NSString *xString = [string substringWithRange:xRange];

    NSLog(@"X = %@, Y = %@", xString, yString);
}
```

*Output:*

```
X = 207.500000, Y = 295.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need following method to call on your string to be trimmed

```
 [yourstring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
```